# How do I use jQuery 'queue' to delay action until series of AJAX events have completed?

Tags: jquery

`enter code here`I have the following code to build select menus dynamically:

```
$j("#id").load('create_menu.cgi', 'view=select_menu');
```

The same menu is used on multiple parts of the page, so rather sending requests over and over to create_menu.cgi, I want to copy from the first one created to the other spots on the page needing the menu.

I have used 'queue' in the past for some things and thought I could use it here. However, it seems like queue in this case will just run once the URL (create_menu.cgi) is called not necessarily after the menu is place in the field. So for example the following is not working:

```
$j("#id").load('create_menu.cgi', 'view=select_menu').queue(function(){

  doSomething();
  $j(this).dequeue;

});
```

doSomething() does not wait until the menu is actually there. Is there a way to use 'queue' for something like this so the menu is copied to the another element on the page immediately following the creation of the first one?

Comment: Are you using the same ID multiple times in the page?

Comment: no, each menu goes under a new id, with the id associated with an optgroup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can instead use the third parameter of the `load` function; the `complete` callback.

`.load( url, [ data ], [ complete(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) ] )`

So, in your case, something like this:

```
$j("#id").load('create_menu.cgi', 'view=select_menu', doSomething);
```

[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Comment: That works, I should've elaborated more in the question in that I am creating multiple optgroups, so it's really something like this:

Comment: $j("#id").load('create_menu.cgi', 'view=select_menu');
$j("#id1").load('create_menu.cgi', 'view=select_menu1');
$j("#id2").load('create_menu.cgi', 'view=select_menu2');

etc.

So I could use the complete function call as the 3rd argument to load() on each one, but I am trying to find a way where I can just call my one function after they have all been loaded with menus.

Comment: So I was hoping to copy the entire menu once

Comment: I think what I'll do is have them load in one call to load and pass a map as an argument and process accordingly in create_menu.cgi, then the complete would work how I want

Comment: apparently I was thinking to hard about this, both of you guys gave good insight in simplicity that helped me implement a good solution of just having my optgroups all predefined in the html with the same class name and then the load would just fill everything so I wouldn't need to use queue or the complete function. Thanks so much for responses from both of you.